# Pass field value from dataset to subreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report which retrieves some fields from DB. Under the main report, I have created a dataset which pulls one more field value  say X from a different table. Now I have a subreport included on this main report. Is it possible to pass field X to the subreport?

Structure:

```
Main Report
 --Dataset1 (retrieves field X)
 --Subreport
```

Note: The field X is basically the average value which I need to pass to subreport which is printed several times based upon the number of results returned by the Main report query.

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio ver 5.6.0*

If not possible, what is the other option to pass this average value field to the subreport

Comment: Are you using regular SQL or Hibernate

Comment: Am using regular SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, so another option will be use another subreport that gets the average. 1stSubreport(that will be in the Main Report) gets the average of the values and then it will have a FinalSubreport, which will get the average value along with anything else it needs

```
Main Report
  --Subreport except Dataset(average field of X)
     --Subreport that retrieves that number
```

If the final Subreport needs also fields from Main Report. Then Pass those values from the Main to the 1stSubReport to the Final Subreport